# Javascript/Jquery : Export Option Tag Value inside a table to CSV FIle

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                 var ctr = 0;
                 var str = "row0";
                 document.write("<button id='add' 
                 onclick='add()''>ADD</button>");
                 document.write("<table id='myTable'></table>");


        function add(){
            var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
            var row = table.insertRow(-1);
            row.id="row"+ctr;
            //alert(row.id);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);

            //alert(ctr);
            if(ctr > 0 ){
            var list = "<select id= 'selectid"+ctr+"' >"+
                            "<option id='none"+ctr+"' value='select' disabled selected = 'true'>Select</option>" +
                            "<option id='parent"+ctr+"' value='Parent'>Parent</option>" +
                            "<option id='child"+ctr+"' value='Child'>Child</option>"+
                        "</select>";
            cell1.innerHTML = list;
            }
            else{
            var list = "<select id= 'selectid"+ctr+"'>"+
                            "<option id='none"+ctr+"' value='select' disabled selected = 'true'>Select</option>" +
                            "<option id='parent"+ctr+"' value='Parent'>Parent</option>" +
                        "</select>";
            cell1.innerHTML = list;             
            }
            ctr += 1;
        }
```

I just want to get the value of the selected  value in the option tag and export or make a download button to put it in a text file. I am planning to use this for offline purposes and only made it in html for the ui.

Comment: Normally you'd do this by submitting the form data to an app engine, and have that return the next page as type text/csv

Comment: thank you for responding but is it possible to do this offline because the webpage itself will only be used offline?

Comment: Not that I am aware of